# Validar campo dependiendo del valor de otro Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, formularios

solicito de su colaboración para que me indique como puedo validar un campo de texto que depende del valor seleccionado en un Radio button; realmente lo que necesito es activar el campo observaciones solamente si se selecciona la opcion 4, pero el formulario lo muetra como invalido.

`Class`

`Class`

```
export class AppComponent {

  testForm: FormGroup;
  msgError: string = 'Este Campo es obligatorio';

  opciones = [
    { nombre: 'N1', valor: 1 },
    { nombre: 'N2', valor: 2 },
    { nombre: 'N3', valor: 3 },
    { nombre: 'Otra Respuesta', valor: 4 },
  ];

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      'opcionA': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'observacionA': new FormControl(null)
    }, {
        validator: this.specificValue
      });
  }

  valido(): boolean {
    return !this.testForm.valid;
  }

  specificValue(group: any) {
    if (!group.controls.opcionA || !group.controls.opcionA.value) return;

    const opcionA = group.controls.opcionA.value;
    let observacionA = group.controls.observacionA.value;
    if (opcionA == '4') {
      if (observacionA) {
        return {
          return: null
        };
      } else {
        return {
          isRequired: true
        };
      }
    }
  }

  guardar() {
    console.log(this.testForm.value);
  }

}
```

`Html`

```
<h1>Form</h1>

<form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="guardar()" novalidate>
  <label *ngFor="let opcion of opciones">
  <input type="radio" 
        formControlName="opcionA"
        required
        [value]="opcion.valor">{{opcion.nombre}}
</label>
  <div *ngIf="testForm.get('opcionA').invalid">
    {{ msgError }}
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="testForm.value.opcionA === 4">
    <textarea formControlName="observacionA"></textarea>
    <div *ngIf="testForm.get('observacionA').invalid">
      {{ msgError }}
    </div>
  </div>
<br>
<hr>
  <button [disabled]="valido"
          type="submit">
  Save
</button>
</form>

{{testForm.valid}}
```

[Demo in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggvo36?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función de validación ha de cumplir la siguiente firma:

```
interface ValidatorFn { 
  (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null
}
```

Tu función no la cumple cuando opcionA no es 4, puesto que no se entra en el bloque `if` y por tanto no se devuelve nada. Eso es equivalente a devolver `undefined`, que no es lo mismo que `null`.

Cuando opcionA es 4, entonces, si observacionA es un valor "verdadero", no estás devolviendo null, sino un objeto equivalente al siguiente:

```
let obj= {
    return: null
}
```

Con lo que tampoco devuelves lo que el framework espera.

Comment: Entiendo loq eu dices, es posible agregarle validacion a el campo observacionA...? @Pablo Lozano